# AudioKit clicking/zipper noise when changing parameter values

Tags: ios, audiokit

I have an iOS app with an AudioKit effects chain, built like this:

```
IN --\ AKEqualizerFilter -- AKLowPassFilter -- AKChorus -- AKDelay -- AKReverb ---|
      \___________________________________________________________________________| DryWet -> OUT
```

The amount of each effect is controlled by its local dry/wet mixer, and the whole chain can be brought in/out using the final dry/wet mixer. I'm finding that I get clicks/zipper noise when moving the sliders controlling individual AU parameters, particularly the reverb and delay. I've tried different options in `AKSettings.bufferLength` and `AKSettings.rampDuration`, but can't seem get rid of it. Are there are any other strategies I might try?

None of the examples I've seen suggest that there's any special way to access the parameters, so they're just being called from our UI, using generic UISliders. However, I did try calling the parameter change off the main thread, but nothing changed.

UPDATE 3: Okay, so digging around more it seems like AKOperationEffect is the way to go, however, I'm still not sure how to control it. I've set it up like this:

```
var delTime = 0.33
if useSync == true {
    let tempo = SequencerController.sharedInstance.currentTempo
    let beatDur = (60000 / tempo) / 1000
    // we'll make the default a dotted-eighth
    delTime = 0.75 * beatDur
}
let opEffect = AKOperationEffect(input) { input, params in
    return input.smoothDelay(time: params[0], feedback: params[1], samples: 1024, maximumDelayTime: 10.0)
}
opEffect.parameters = [delTime, 0.]
```

where `input` is from the previous node -- so, in this chain, from the chorus. This does get me the delay `time` (without zippering!) but I can't find a way to control the dry/wet mix. Is this not possible with AKOperationEffect perhaps?